# want to access data in an child grid view but it was showing me "No Matching Record Found"

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and MYSQL I am working on code first approach and here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#propgrid").on("expand-row.bs.table", function (e, index, row, $detail) {
            debugger
             $detail.html('<div class="ml-20 mr-20"><table class="table table-bordered text-center"></table></div>').find('table').bootstrapTable({                
                    columns: [{
                        field: "Bathroom",
                        title: "Bathroom",
                        sortable: true,
                    }, {
                        field: "Bedroom",
                        title: "Bedroom",
                        sortable: true,
                     }, {
                         field: "FurnishingType",
                        title: "FurnishingType",
                        sortable: true,
                     }
                 ],
                 data: row,
                    sidePagination: 'properties',
                    sortName: "Bathroom",
                    pagination: true
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing your code. Now what is your question here?

Comment: i want to show data in child grid but its not accessing and that my issue while debugging i am getting the data in row but not in $details it passess null why i dont get it